# Move controller method to client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to move a controller method to client side, not knowing where to start. Could anyone help me with this.

In the controller method, I am getting the count of some active items from the database using entity framework.

Method:

```
    public LocationModel GetActiveChasesCountByLocation(string locationKey)
    {
        try
        {
            string _stateName = string.Empty;
            Suit_2013SQLEntities context = BusinessUtils.GetQshrDBContext(_stateName);

            BusinessUtils.ConfigureDbContextForDataLoad(context);

            var location = from loc in context.Locations.Include("Providers").Include("HRChases")
                           where loc.LocationKey == locationKey
                           select new LocationModel
                           {
                               LocationKey = loc.LocationKey,
                               LocationName = loc.LocationName,
                               LocationCity = loc.LocationCity,
                               LocationState = loc.LocationState,
                               IsActiveChaseExists = loc.Providers.Any(p => p.HRChases.Any(c => c.ChaseStatus == "A" || c.ChaseStatus == "Q")) ? "Active" : "In Active",
                               ActiveChaseCount = loc.Providers.Count() > 0 ? loc.Providers.Sum(p => p.HRChases.Count(c => c.ChaseStatus == "A" || c.ChaseStatus == "Q")) : 0
                           };

            return location.FirstOrDefault<LocationModel>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help!

Comment: You want to query the DB from the client side? Are you sure that's what you want to do? Really?

Comment: Btw, it's much better to rethrow like this: `catch (Exception ex){ throw; }` so you don't lose your callstack

Comment: that was what i have been asked to do :(

Comment: So will the database be at the client side too?

Comment: I am really confused here, I dont know how to go about it.. kind off stuck..

Comment: Perhaps you think that's what you've been asked, but I doubt it really is. Better double check.

Comment: First of all, You need DB that enable REST.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the response. Actually, what I did was called the same method in the controller through DataBound event of the grid. I did this in the Client Side. This satisfied my lead! ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the response. Actually, what I did was called the same method in the controller through DataBound event of the grid. I did this in the Client Side. This satisfied my lead! ;)